# How do I set XAML FlowDocument MaxPageWidth in millimeters?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to do an Document file in `XAML` and I need to set the Width and Height with equivalent values to an A4 sheet`(Width: 210mm. Heigth: 297mm).`

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After short Googling, I found this:

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.pagewidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use the second version:

```
<object PageWidth="qualifiedDouble"/>
```

*qualifiedDouble*

```
A double value as described above, followed by one of the following unit specifiers: px, in, cm, pt.
```

- px (default) is device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit)
- in is inches; 1in==96px
- cm is centimeters; 1cm==(96/2.54) px
- pt is points; 1pt==(96/72) px

It's the same with PageHeight, so overall I think using it this way could solve your problem:

```
<FlowDocument PageWidth="21cm" PageHeight="29.7cm" />
```